# Regarding map different implementation

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, guava

I have following Map..

```
Map<String, Collection<Integer>> multiValueMap = new HashMap<String, Collection<Integer>>();
         multiValueMap.put("a", new ArrayList<Integer>());
         multiValueMap.get("a").add(new Integer(10));
         multiValueMap.get("a").add(new Integer(20));
         multiValueMap.get("a").add(new Integer(30));

         System.out.println("There are "+multiValueMap.size()+" elements in the map.");
         System.out.println("Content of multiValueMap are...");
         Set s=multiValueMap.entrySet();
         Iterator itr=s.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext())
         {
             Map.Entry m=(Map.Entry)itr.next();
             System.out.println(m.getKey()+"\t"+m.getValue()+"\t"+ m.hashCode());
          }
```

and the output of this is..

```
There are 1 elements in the map.
Content of multiValueMap are...
a   [10, 20, 30]    39954
```

Please advise can same thing be achieved through Guava Multimap also and if then please advise..!!

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Answer (score 1):

```
 Multimap<String, Integer> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
 multimap.putAll("a", ImmutableList.of(10, 20, 30));
 System.out.println("There are " + multimap.keySet().size() +
     " elements in the map.");
 System.out.println("Content of multimap are...");
 for (Map.Entry<String, Collection<Integer>> asMapEntry :
     multimap.asMap().entrySet()) {
   System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s%n", asMapEntry.getKey(), asMapEntry.getValue(),
       asMapEntry.hashCode());
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of *keys* in a `MultiMap` one can use [`Multimap.keySet().size()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#keySet%28%29)

You can also iterate this set and use [`Multimap.get(key)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html#get%28K%29)
 to get a collection of all the values attached to this key.